# androidTestCompile runtime dependency doesn't work on android 5.0+

Tags: android, jdbc, android-espresso, android-testing

So I wrote an instrumental test that performs some changes in my database on my localhost server. I used just `jdbc` raw query, nothing special.

- On Android < 5.0 instrumental tests run ok
- On Android starting from 5.0 (doesn't matter if it's an emulator or real device) instrumentalTests classLoader throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource`. Note my tests do not even start.
- I do have mysql in dependencies and I don't use proguard in debug mode that can strip it out.
- If I specify `mysql-connector-java` as `compile` instead of `androidTestCompile` it works after android 5.0 as well. So the problem is `androidTestCompile` doesn't append mysql lib to instrumental environment.

Why does android 5.0 doesn't detect `androidTestCompile` dependency? Here's what I got:

**build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    androidTestCompile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6"
}
```

**androidTest/java/my.package.Mytest**:

Note that I load mysql lib via `Class.forName`

```
import java.sql.*; // some java.sql imports, no mysql dependencies in imports.

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginTest { 

   @Rule
   public final ActivityTestRule<MainScreen> main = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainScreen.class);


    @Test
    public void checkLoginFlow() throws InterruptedException {
        // Login/Sign up flow
        assertEquals("App is not loaded", MainScreen.class, getCurrentActivity());

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       ....
```

**Here's the full log**:

```
Testing started at 1:12 PM ...

01/17 13:12:50: Launching UITest
$ adb push /tmp/MyApp/app/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.MyApp
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.MyApp"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.MyApp
Success


$ adb push /tmp/MyApp/app/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.MyApp.test
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.MyApp.test"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.MyApp.test
Success


Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug true com.MyApp.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Waiting for application to come online: com.MyApp | com.MyApp.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.MyApp | com.MyApp.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.MyApp | com.MyApp.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.MyApp | com.MyApp.test
Connecting to com.MyApp
I/art: Debugger is active
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8657', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1434)
I/AndroidJUnitRunner: Debugger connected.
I/MonitoringInstrumentation: Instrumentation Started!
I/MonitoringInstrumentation: Setting context classloader to 'dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.MyApp.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.MyApp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.MyApp.test-2/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.MyApp-2/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]]', Original: 'dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.MyApp.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.MyApp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.MyApp.test-2/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.MyApp-2/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]]'
I/MonitoringInstrumentation: No JSBridge.
I/UsageTrackerFacilitator: Usage tracking enabled
I/TestRequestBuilder: Scanning classpath to find tests in apks [/data/app/com.MyApp.test-2/base.apk]
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester>
E/TestLoader: Could not find class: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter>
E/TestLoader: Could not find class: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker>
E/TestLoader: Could not find class: com.mysql.jdbc.integration.jboss.MysqlValidConnectionChecker
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAConnection>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAConnection>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4MysqlXAConnection>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4MysqlXAConnection>
E/TestLoader: Could not find class: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4MysqlXAConnection
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.SuspendableXAConnection>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.SuspendableXAConnection>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4SuspendableXAConnection>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4SuspendableXAConnection>
E/TestLoader: Could not find class: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4SuspendableXAConnection
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource>
E/TestLoader: Could not find class: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource>

       --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
                  Process: com.MyApp, PID: 4088
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                      at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doLoadClass(TestLoader.java:92)
                      at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.loadIfTest(TestLoader.java:113)
                      at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.loadClassesFromClassPath(TestRequestBuilder.java:801)
                      at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:747)
                      at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:354)
                      at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:260)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)

Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
Tests ran to completion.
```